# C circular array

Tags: c, algorithm

I want to make a circular array of a fixed size, and I want to add elements to it and then should be able to print it, when the array is full the new added elements should take place of the old elements

example

```
...

list_add('a');  //add element 'a'
list_add('b');  //add element 'b'
list_add('c');  //add element 'c'

list_print();  // should print 'a', 'b', 'c'

list_add('d');  //add element 'd'
list_add('e');  //add element 'e'

list_print();  // should print 'c', 'd', 'e'
...
```

at first I though , it would be easy with some hack but it gave me a headache :(
here is what I did

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void list_add(char element);
void list_print();

char list[3] = {0, 0, 0};
int idx = 0;

int main(){

    list_add('a');
    list_add('b');
    list_add('c');
    list_print();

    list_add('d');
    list_add('e');
    list_print();

    return 0;
}

void list_add(char element){
    list[idx] = element;
    idx++;
    if(idx==3) idx=0;
}
void list_print(){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) printf("%c\n", list[i]);
}
```

Comment: What's exactly your problem? Hint: use modulo operator.

Comment: @slnowak the problem when I print them , the order is wrong

Comment: Because you simply iterate over the table. You should somehow remember where's yout current start and end position.

Comment: People here like to downvote every question. This one doesn't deserve the downvote.

Comment: @slnowak I tried to make 2 variables to save first and last elements , but didn't work for me or at least I don't know how to use them to do what I want

Comment: @JuanLopes thank you, I don't really know why they downvoted me, at least they can leave a comment to tell why.

Comment: @acclav There's a tendency for people to down vote things they think are easy. It's not really fair on novices.

Comment: I didn't downvote this, but lets see..  No question.  No output results. No aparrent attempt at debugging.  That should do for now.

Comment: In general, it's not easy/complex that gets downvotes, it's BAD QUESTIONS that either should not have been asked at all, or don't provide information that is useful to any contributors who may wish to look.  Not including inputs/outputs, error-messages, log entries and whatever has already been discovered by the OP's own debugging efforts are all likely to result in downvotes.

Comment: Furthermore, contributors don't leave comments on downvotes because they would rather spend their time answering good questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define SIZE 3
char list[SIZE] = {0};
//...
void list_print(void){
    int n = SIZE;
    int i = idx;

    while(n--){
        printf("%c ", list[i++ % SIZE]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to print out from the oldest element look at your `list_add` code and your `list_print`.

`list_add` 'knows' where the insertion point is but `list_print` always starts from 0.

You probably want to start from `idx` as the 'oldest' element.
I would check to see if it is `0` as they are 'empty' slots before the circle is complete.

Try:

```
void list_print(){
    int i=idx;//Start at the insertion point - just after the last insert - if any.
    do{
        if(list[i]!=0){//Don't output unfilled entries. Just a suggestion.
            //You can't now store 0 but that's probably OK for most purposes.
            printf("%c\n", list[i]);
        }
        ++i;//Increment i and watch for looping like you did in list_add().
        if(i==3){
            i=0;
        }
    }while(i!=idx);//Stop when we're back at the beginning.
 }
```

Comment: You could replace if block with i = i++ % size;

Comment: @slnowak  `i = i++ % size;` is wrong. it's might UB.

Comment: @slnowak Sure could. But I thought we'd walk before we try running! I just copied what the OP did.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a chance that you just haven't noticed that your code is fine? It works the way it should. You add a, b, c. Then you add d and e which replace the array circularly: d, e, c. Illustration:

```
{0,0,0}
{a,0,0}
{a,b,0}
{a,b,c}
{d,b,c}
{d,e,c}
```

Or am I missing something here?

Is that the way you wanted?

```
int indicator = 0;
<...>
void list_add(char element) {
    if((idx < 3) && !indicator) { 
    list[idx] = element; idx++;
} else {
    indicator = 1;
    list[idx - 1] = element; idx--;
    if (idx == 0) {
        idx = 3;
    }
};
```

And what about now? :)

```
void list_add(char element){
    if((idx < 3) && !indicator) { 
        list[idx] = element; idx++;
    } else {
        indicator = 1;
        list[idx - 3] = list[idx - 2];
        list[idx - 2] = list[idx -1];
        list[idx - 1] = element;
    };
}
```

It fills the array normally until 3. Then it loops by shifting all the elements and then inserts a new value. You will have to add some dynamics to it (loop) if you want to create, lets say, a dynamic array.

Comment: OP would like his list to be printed from oldest entry to the newest one.

Comment: I got it. But then it's not a circle anymore.

Comment: as slnowak said , the output should be {c,d,e} from oldest to newest, maybe I called it wrong because I really don't know what its called :)

Comment: @ŽilvinasVerseckas no, that gave me a {a,e,d} which is not what I want